# finding other user according to my location

Tags: java, android, android-gps, geofire

I'm using firebase (android) to store data and I'm saving users like below:

```
users{
    abcdefghi{
      name:"abc",
      lat:"12.988",
      long:-0.123,
      desc:"all other desc"
    },KLMNGHT{
        name:"def",
        lat:"11.988",
        long:-1.123,
        desc:" other desc"
    }
}
```

I want to display all users who comes into my radius zone(proximity zone) which are defined by me according to my location . I am out of ideas . I looked upon Haversine formula. But i don't know to achieve that.

What is the best algorithm to find user?

Comment: Can possibly look into using geofire - https://github.com/firebase/geofire-java

Comment: Please consider adding more steps you've taken to achieve the desired result.  Going from lat,long to a full algorithm showing users is quite the problem.

Comment: @michaelcarrano cannot be able to use geofire bec right now it supports older version of firebase

Comment: @FishStix i didn't get your point of adding more steps ?

Comment: @Davin have you taken a look at https://github.com/firebase/geofire-java/tree/geofire-2 which is being worked on to support the latest firebase sdk. Haven't actually tested it myself to see how stable it is.

Answer (score 1):

```
private const double EARTH_RADIUS = 6378.137;
private static double rad(double d)
{
   return d * Math.PI / 180.0;
}

public static double GetDistance(double lat1, double lng1, double lat2, double lng2)
{
   double radLat1 = rad(lat1);
   double radLat2 = rad(lat2);
   double a = radLat1 - radLat2;
   double b = rad(lng1) - rad(lng2);

   double s = 2 * Math.Asin(Math.Sqrt(Math.Pow(Math.Sin(a/2),2) +
    Math.Cos(radLat1)*Math.Cos(radLat2)*Math.Pow(Math.Sin(b/2),2)));
   s = s * EARTH_RADIUS;
   s = Math.Round(s * 10000) / 10000;
   return s;
}
```

Maybe this code can help you.

Answer (score 1):

So is the question strictly: given two points on earth A(lan1,lon1) B(lan2,lon2) find the distance between A and B? When you are saying 'best algorithm',do you mean best in terms of development time,time,memory?!

Anyways,assuming 'best' in terms of development time you could use:
1.Google's API explained here: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/distance-matrix/intro#DistanceMatrixRequests

2.Here is a simple implementation- but I haven't tested it myself yet-
https://www.geodatasource.com/developers/java

Comment: @ Yoni Keren best algo mean to say best way . Like how can filter the user . In 2 point example i need to put other user long, lat every time to calculate distance . is that only best approach to filter user according to my location ? Anyway thanks

Comment: Oh I see,That's the most naive way. If you are going to have tens of millions of users,since this will go through each one of them, it might not be the most efficient. Given your own location, say (lan1,lon1) if you want to find all the users such that their location (lan2,lon2) is within the proximity of X kms of your location, out of the top of my head you can sort their table so that lan2 is between two values AND lon2 is between two values. Remember that unless you have many many users,it's probably not worth your time right now. This is a server side code-You can imporove that later.

Comment: To do that efficiently, you might want to store the users in some balanced binary tree according to lan, and another one according to lon, and then finding the users between those values will take log(N) where N is number of users.